# Background image takes while to load in wordpress divi theme

Tags: css, wordpress, image

I have a [website](https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/) in which the header background image takes while to load.

I have applied **background image in the section module settings** as shown below with **Parallax effect** on.

[image]

The CSS codes applied on the background image is:

```
element.style {
    background-image: url();
    height: 627px;
    transform: translate(0px, 101.1px);
}

.et_parallax_bg {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**Problem Statement**

I am wondering is there anything I need to add in the CSS codes in order to make the background image loads faster or I need to resize the image.

Comment: I'd just use gimp and resize it personally.

Comment: @Scath No changes needed on the CSS codes ?

Comment: I had this same issue and couldn't find anything. You can also lower the quality in gimp. I think I took all mine down to like 75 or 80 you can't tell the difference.

Comment: I use adobe photoshop. I am wondering how I can do it there. Do you me to resize it to 75 %  or 80 % of theimage ?

Comment: No gimp is free and it has a tool to lower the quality of an image https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpnIJLFLZGc

Comment: @Scath I will try with that and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your image; nothing to do with CSS or the theme.
Try to optimize your image using some online image optimizers.

Google: **image optimizer online** or **image compressor online**.
here is a suggestion: [www.optimizilla.com](http://optimizilla.com) ; this will fix load time and maintain image quality.

Your current background info: 4793x1905px widthxheight and file size is 924KB which almost 1MB.

I wonder why do you plan such size?

try this optimized image and let us know the result?

[image: try to use this optimized] image: 1900x755px and 139KB.

In old times the standard page should be more more than 150KB all.

In Photoshop try the following to reduce image size and quality:

A) Photoshop Menu --> Image --> Image size ... then adjust

[image]

B) When you save as PNG try to adjust quality to something fair:

[image]

And this is [how to in GIMP](https://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-tutorial-quickie-scale.html).

Or you can try [online image resize](https://imageresize.org) for both image size and quality.

Note: Not only the image causing your website to load slow; you might need some WordPress Speed Optimization guru or to research internet how to do it.

You have lots of speed issue in your website.

Check this and compare:

[image]

This is the speed of loading current backgound.

[image]

This is the speed for optimized image (Still big size and quality though)

[image]

This is whole site's front page load time; too big size and slow load time.